# Cucumber 5 - How to parse data table with headers using default jackson transformer

Tags: jackson, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have cucumber data tables with headers, and I am wondering how to parse them with Jackson when they have headers. I have the following configuration. This seems to work as long as everything is a String. But if my object contains for instance a Double, then when it tries to parse the header for that column it will choke on the column name. How can I tell it to skip the header?

```
private final ObjectMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper()//
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())//
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)//
        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)//
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

@DefaultParameterTransformer
@DefaultDataTableEntryTransformer
@DefaultDataTableCellTransformer
public Object defaultTransformer(Object fromValue, Type toValueType) {
    JavaType javaType = csvMapper.constructType(toValueType);
    return csvMapper.convertValue(fromValue, javaType);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your table, your dto, and your step definition?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to load it in as a Map<String, BigDecimal> and the the header was throwing me off. I just created an object and it was fine. It's ultimately a very minor inconvenience

Comment: Also you definitely shouldn't use a csvmapper, needs to be an objectmapper